# How to finish spacing in different lines in Python

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

My task is to ask user input and then save into a text file while using array or lists. After that the things I save into the text file should have only the values entered by the user, nothing extra like the brackets of the array. The values to be printed in the text file are to be printed on separate lines.( I have done this, problems ahead!) Afterwards I have to read the values entered and then display them. During displaying them they have gaps of 1-2 lines in between, I can't finish that. I will mention the code.
Code:

```py
name_input = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of times you want to input: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    name = input("Enter the input: ")
    name_input.append(name)

    


f = open("userFile.txt","w")
for i in range(0,n):
    f.write(str(name_input[i]) + "\n" )
    
f.close()

g = open("userFile.txt","r")
print("These are the elemets you have printed: ")

for i in g:
    print(*i,sep = "\n")
g.close()
```

[image I mentioned of text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuheK.png)

I tried removing the values printing in different lines of a text file, it worked but in the text file the values shall print in separate lines. I simply cant finish the gap, tried a lot

Comment: rather than `print(*i,sep = "\n")` you can `print(i.strip())`

Comment: when you read from file line by line, you read also the new line, thus you don't need to ass `sep='\n'` when print. That would be an extra blank line

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the space by calling the append method

```
name_input = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of times you want to input: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    name = input("Enter the input: ")
    name_input.append(name)  

f = open("userFile.txt","w")
for i in range(0,n):
    f.write(str(name_input[i]))
    
f.close()

g = open("userFile.txt","r")
print("These are the elemets you have printed: ")

for i in g:
    print(*i,sep = "\n")
g.close()
```

Comment: This is printing each character on a different line for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rstrip()` method to remove any newline characters `\n` from the end of each line when reading from the file like this:

```
name_input = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of times you want to input: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    name = input("Enter the input: ")
    name_input.append(name)

f = open("userFile.txt","w")
for i in range(0,n):
    f.write(str(name_input[i]) + "\n")
f.close()

g = open("userFile.txt","r")
print("These are the elements you have printed: ")
for i in g:
    print(i.rstrip())
g.close()
```